# ERROR CON AuthenticatesUsers

Tags: laravel

estoy tratando de realizar la autenticacion de los usuarios  con ldaprecord y ya realize la mayoria de los pasos pero me sale este error en la ruta de logincontoller.php
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estuve revisando consultas parecidas y decia que ejecutara composer require laravel/ui pero ya lo ejecute y instala bien  lo que entiendo es que no encuentra illumunate .....ect  en versiones anteriores de laravel habia unos archivos que tenian estos datos pero en laravel 8 estan incluidos en laravel framewor alguien tiene idea de como solucionarlo

error sobre " use AuthenticatesUsers;

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/laragon/www/laravel/FORMULARIOS/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "1009",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined type 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Auth\\AuthenticatesUsers'.",
    "source": "intelephense",
    "startLineNumber": 23,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 23,
    "endColumn": 27
}
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: Tanto el código como el mensaje de error van como texto por favor

Comment: Eso no es problema de Laravel, es problema del plugin `intelephense`, desactiva el plugin y pruebalo